# How to edit ENTRYPOINT file of a docker image

Tags: docker

I did a basic search in the community and could not find a suitable answer, so I am asking here. Sorry if it was asked earlier.

Basic questions, I have a docker image that when run, executes the entrypoint script and exits. The entrypoint script basically prints 'Hello,World!'. 
3 questions.

1. How do I keep the container alive?
2. If the container is alive, can I ssh into it and edit the entrypoint script?
3. If I edit the entry point script, should I rebuild the image or will it be saved there for good?

Thanks

Comment: I tried running 'docker run -d <image>' , but still the container is not showing up in docker ps

Comment: When the ENTRYPOINT completes, the container exits. Try `echo "hello" ; sleep infinity`

Answer (score 1):

1. Entrypoint is a primary function of the container. So as soon as
   it has stopped the container will exit.

   To keep the container alive just point the entrypoint at something
   that doesn't stop.
2. Yes, but I am unsure if the script would run the new version, by next run.
3. You need to save the docker image, next time once docker image is run it should run the new entrypoint script.

I suggest you should look into `dockerfile`, it means you prepare all the files and the docker image without having to SSH into the container. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/